# WKWebView does not re-render content while loading another URL

Tags: ios, objective-c, webkit, wkwebview

I'm currently developing an application that uses a `UIWebView` to display some content. It used to work fine with `UIWebView`, but we decided to switch to `WKWebView` when we raised the OS requirement to 8.1. We noticed a huge improvement in performance, but some simple think that used to work fine, started failing now. After some research, I managed to see what's going on - but I don't see how to fix it. I was wondering if someone could lend me a hand on this...

The URL our webview loads takes quite a lot of time to finish the job, so before starting the request we load a static spinner so the user doesn't feel like the app has gone nuts. The load cycle for that static content is already tuned up, so we don't start the URL request until the static content has been correcty loaded. This works fine, as long as the user doesn't rotate the device. This is what can be seen:

(I had to change the view for privacy purposes. I'm not the owner of this code, after all :-))

[image]

I'm using this html code to test the size. The body's background color is dark gray, and the ugly light gray box expands to the 100% of the width, substracting the margins. So far so good. But if the user rotates the device, this is what happens:

[image]

This is creepy, since apparently the body's stetching to match the maximum width, but the inner div is handling a wrong relative size. This goes on as long as the request is being processed. When I force a timeout to make the request fail, the `WKWebView` re-renders and shows its correct appearance:

[image]

Once I discovered this I tried, without success, to subscribe to the rotation observer and force re-renders on the webview by:

- Calling `viewNeedsDisplay` for both the `UIWebView` and the `UIScrollView` inside
- Re-sizing the `UIWebView`
- Re-positioning the `UIScrollView` content

So, my conclusions so far:

- This didn't happen on an `UIWebView`, just on the new `WKWebView` (I tested this again, confirmed)
- Looks like `WKWebView` doesn't render views correctly while it's on loading status

Does somebody know if there's a way to fix this? Something like one magical property I'm missing that comes disabled by default? I don't want to think they broke this part when they remade the webview... Thanks in advance :)

**Edit:** Stuff I tried since the creation of the post, without success:

- Changing the DOM asyncronally, through the use of javascript/native rotation callbacks **doesn't work**. The changes don't get rendered until the http request ends.
- Calling the http request in a different thread using the `dispatch_async` method **doesn't work**. Under the hood, the `WKWebview` probably ends up using the same thread as if you call it from the main thread.

Comment: Try manually refreshing the page on an orientation change? I don't know the exact code you would use

Comment: I can't do that. After all, if you didn't miss the point in the explanation, this issue happens when you're expecting an answer from another request, so if I refresh the page that would launch a new request, discarding the old one... and blocking the app ;)

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I think I'm running into a similar issue moving around a WKWebview that has video running in it.

Comment: Nope :( Still no luck with this

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind getting a bit hacky, there are ways to do it with Javascript:

1. You could add Javascript that detects changes such as `window.orientation` and `window.onresize`. See if any frame-related event gets called. If they are called, simply resize the div yourself with Javascript.
2. If the events never get fired, you can fake them yourself using [evaluateJavaScript:completionHandler:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKWebView_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKWebView/evaluateJavaScript:completionHandler:)
3. You could also make your own events that way. Simply send a resize div script whenever you detect a change in the device's orientation within your app.
4. If you are loading Javascript, you could look at the `async` and `defer` of the `<script>` tag. This means you will have to change the code in the webview.

It's not the best way of approaching this, but it will require the least amount of change.

I also suggest you fill a bug report at https://bugreport.apple.com/, so that you can know if it is an expected behavior or not.

Comment: I don't know if this is going to work, because I think the issue is related to the UI thread getting blocked by the incoming Http request. I recall trying to modify the DOM asyncronally with the Safari dev console, and it didn't start rendering the changes until the request did finish loading so... I don't think adding events will make a difference. In fact, I don't know if I'll be able to position that view manually, but I'll try anyway :) Thanks for your insight.

Answer (score 0):

While I don't have a solution for the `WKWebView` not rendering while loading content, I would suggest a different fix to your problem.

You can change the loading view from a page loaded in the webview to a native iOS view. Just add a subview to the main view, above the webview when you start loading and remove it when the loading is finished. This would work fine with the rotation and so you can have the same experience as you had before.

Another solution would be to load your loading view in a `UIWebView` as you did before that works fine with rotation and the normal page in the `WKWebView` behind it. When the page is loaded you also just hide, or remove the `UIWebView`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We've thought of changing to a native view, but it's difficult to integrate in our code due to our particular structure, so I'm affraid I'll resort to this only if there's no other way around...

Comment: I see. Well you can always use the second solution, to add a `UIWebView` which you know it works, as a subview, and then remove it when loading is finished.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant. The problem is how natively adding/removing the UIWebView affects our current flow :)